# Strip numbers from JSON response in Rails 3?

Tags: regex, database, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am receiving a JSON post into my Rails 3 application. I am then parsing each of the values and inserting them into the application database. It's all working well but now I would like to modify the received values before inserting them into the database.

```
:subject => email_payload['subject']
```

As the above code shows, I am inserting the received value for 'subject' into the column named 'subject'.

In the example above the received value is like this:

```
Results from Example Company - Surname/Firstname/[12345]
```

What I would like to do is strip everything out except the numerical value between the []. So the value that's inserted into the database is simply:

```
12345
```

I can, presumably, just select anything from 0-9 but how do I add regex to the received string?

None of the following seem to work:

```
['subject.gsub!([0-9])']
['subject'.gsub!([0-9])]
['subject'].gsub!([0-9])
```

I've tested the Regex here http://rubular.com/r/AVFkm3A440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are applying the `.gsub()` to the value returned by the hash key `email_payload['subject']`, the method belongs chained outside the closing `]`.

Your regular expression is missing its `/` delimiters. To capture the group as a whole, add a `+` as in `/[^0-9]+/`. The `^` will match all non-digit characters, and then `.gsub()` will replace them with an empty string. So the pattern below will mutate the key `email_payload['subject']` in place

```
email_payload['subject'] = 'Results from Example Company - Surname/Firstname/[12345]'

email_payload['subject'].gsub!(/[^0-9]+/, '')
>> "12345"
# gsub!() has mutated the value:
puts email_payload['subject']
>> 12345
```

Comment: If I use `email_payload['subject'].gsub!(/[^0-9]+/, '')` is there a way of stopping it from overriding 'subject' if I parse it again? If I do 'email_payload['subject']` before or after the regex it filters out the letters again.

Comment: @dannymcc If you don't want to overwrite it, use `.gsub()` instead of `.gsub!()`

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to have the original subject in one column and the modified subject in a second column. Doing it with the suggested code overrides both columns.

Comment: @dannymcc Both columns of what? Your example above only stores a `:subject` key.  If you want both the original and the modified version, first store the original then store the modified version.  `:subject_orig => email_payload['subject'], :subject => email_payload['subject'].gsub(....)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed your earlier comment regarding gsub! & gsub. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Examples from Ruby [documentation for String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

```
"hello".gsub(/[aeiou]/, '*')                  #=> "h*ll*"
"hello".gsub(/([aeiou])/, '<\1>')             #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
"hello".gsub(/./) {|s| s.ord.to_s + ' '}      #=> "104 101 108 108 111 "
"hello".gsub(/(?<foo>[aeiou])/, '{\k<foo>}')  #=> "h{e}ll{o}"
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

So gsub is used to substitute pattern globally on the string.

You probably need `scan`.

```
"Results from Example Company - Surname/Firstname/[12345]".
   scan(/\[(\d*)\]$/).
   flatten
>> ["12345"]
```

This presumes that the digits you want to select come inside `[]` brackets and that `]` is in the end of the string.

Comment: Somehow your example seems to result in just one digit showing.